# What is the difference between opening the command prompt with ShellExecute() vs. by hand?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, command-prompt, shellexecute

I'm trying to run a java program via a windows program I created as a sort of "Launcher" application. Normally to run this java program I would either run a batch file or go directly to the cmd prompt window (Windows Key + R, type "cmd") and enter `java -Xmx4096M -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true [...]`. The point is that **java** seems to be recognized in this window.

On the other hand, when I launch the command prompt from my application, java is no longer "recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
if(SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_SYSTEM, NULL, 0, szPath))) {
    PathAppend(szPath, TEXT("cmd.exe"));
    ShellExecuteW( GetSafeHwnd(),L"open", szPath, NULL, NULL, 1 );
}
```

### Why is this so?

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are running this code on the 64-bit version of Windows.  So you'll likely started the 32-bit version of cmd.exe that doesn't know beans about a 64-bit version of java.

Comment: @HansPassant: That sounds unlikely; environment variables are bitness-independent.

Comment: I'm pointing to the *same* executable as the one as clicked on by hand if I were to go into the directory and open it myself. `AfxMessageBox(szPath);` after PathAppend() confirms this... are you suggesting that whether it runs as 32bit vs 64bit is independent of the executable? Also, `echo %PATH%` spits out the same paths, except two additional MSVC++ include libraries are added to the one I launch from my program.

Comment: Try `where java` in both prompts

Comment: File requests made by 32-bit executables for any files in c:\windows\system32 get redirected automatically to c:\windows\syswow64.  Use Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab to check this.  If my crystal ball is right then you'll see cmd.exe running with the *32 annotation.

Comment: @SLaks - regular cmd prompt: `C:\Windows\System32\java.exe` my launcher's cmd prompt: `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`

Comment: @HansPassant - What you told me to look for appears to be true. The cmd prompt my launcher opens is `*32`. What's interesting is that going to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` manually and running the cmd.exe there... this one also does not recognize java. Only manually running the cmd.exe in \System32 correctly finds java, and yet that's the one I'm specifying in my code (and yet magically doesn't recognize java)... Neither specification (CSIDL_SYSTEM vs. CSIDL_SYSTEMX86) works in the code.

Comment: Yup.  Building your program as a 64-bit executable is an obvious workaround.  The next one is to use CSIDL_WINDOWS and append "sysnative".  The next one is to call Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(), probably best since you really ought to use the ComSpec environment variable to find the command processor.

Comment: Thx, I was able to get it working with your last solution. Regarding the other solution (just out of curiosity), I don't even have a `sysnative` on my computer... is that standard? (Win 7 Professional x64)

Comment: @IDontWorkAtNASA: sysnative will be there (for 32-bit processes!) but it doesn't show up in listings.  It's a virtual directory, not a real one.

Comment: @SLaks: Java doesn't add itself to the path, it just sticks a copy of `java.exe` into the `system32` folder.  OP: note that this particular problem would go away if you installed the 32-bit Java runtime as well as the 64-bit Java runtime.  Of course, depending on what it's doing, you may prefer for your Java code to run in a 64-bit VM.

Answer (score 3):

#### For future visitors who have this problem, here's my working solution:

```
PVOID OldValue = NULL;
if( Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&OldValue) )  {
        TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    if(SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_SYSTEM, NULL, 0, szPath))) {
        PathAppend(szPath, TEXT("cmd.exe"));
        ShellExecuteW( GetSafeHwnd(), L"open", szPath, NULL, NULL, 1 );
    }
    if ( FALSE == Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(OldValue) ) {
        AfxMessageBox(L"A script that should never fail has failed.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Thanks to [HansPassant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) for leading me in the right direction.